# Does Negative Prompting Exist?

Tags: llm, prompt-engineering

All the prompt engineering techniques I've seen seem to focus on telling the model what to do e.g. Few-Shot Prompting.

Is there any value in giving the model examples of what not to do? Can you link me to any papers/techniques on the topic?

**Example**

I am building a bot to improve students' foreign language writing skills.

```
Bad output: Corrected spelling of 'heisse' to 'heiße' because 'heiße' is the correct spelling in German.

Better output: Corrected spelling of 'heisse' to 'heiße' because 'ss' can be combined to form 'ß' in German.
```

I could solve this specific problem using few-shot prompting. But really, I want to tell the model "don't give answers like 'this is how it is done in German', instead explain what is being done and the reasons for it".

I may have answered my own question there... just put it what I said above in the system prompt?

Comment: yes it seems to be one of the exemple where you cna complement the student prompt by "i am a student please explain in details"

Answer (score 1):

> Does Negative Prompting Exist?

Yes, e.g. in some text-to-image generation models such as https://app.leonardo.ai/ai-generations:

[image]

One can run such negative prompts on one's computer, e.g. with [Automatic1111's Stable Diffusion WebUI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) ([Windows 10/11 installer](https://github.com/EmpireMediaScience/A1111-Web-UI-Installer)):

[image]

Takes ~8GB though:

[image]